Google Cloud Sign In with Python using user credentials in a browser
In Azure one can use the InteractivebrowserCredentials() to allow a user to log into Azure via python and enter their credentials in a browser authentication window.
GCP seems to restate using default environment credentials which is not useful for my case. Is there a way to authenticate using a browser UI from Google which then passes the credentials and token through to the script or application being ran?
Tried multiple libraries from google and nothing that is not deprecated seems to have this functionality. Might just lose the rest of my hair trying to figure this out

Can you edit your question to add a bit more detail around your specific use case and a bit more specifics around the authentication flow you're looking to have implemented? It sounds like you're looking to implement an OAuth2-style authorization code flow (as is what InteractiveBrowserCredential helps with), but without more details regarding what it is you're trying to authenticate/authorize the solutions you'll get may not get you where you want.
